# Central limit theorem with multiple samples

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, central-limit-theorem

Hi I was wondering about the following problem:

If there are $1000$ students in a school and the combined scores of these students over the last $5$ years are  $5823, 6107, 5672, 6233$ and $5598$ respectively. What is the estimated number of students who this year score between $10$ and $20$.

I am unsure how to approach this solution and specifically unsure whether to use the random variable $X$ as the random variable for the combined score or the individual score. For example if $X$ is the combined scores then I could take $\hat{\mu}=\frac{1}{5}\sum \frac{X}{1000}$ then calculate the variance in a similar manner before applying this to the formula:

$$ P ( 10 < X < 20 ) \\
P\bigg( \frac{10-\hat{\mu}}{\frac{\hat{\sigma}}{\sqrt{N}}}< Z <  ..\bigg) $$

Then upon calulating this probabiltiy I could simply multiply it by 1000 to get the estimated number of players in that range.

Any advice would be appreciated, even if not particular to this problem.

Thanks.